# Is The Analysis of Happiness in Episode 22 of NHK ni Youkoso Related to Real Study?

Tags: welcome-to-the-nhk

In Ep 22, an analysis is mentioned by Nakahara, saying that we have 10% happy moments in our life, and other 90% is in misery. Is this related to a real psychological study? If so, how can I find the related work, any reference?

#### The scene at 18:20 in Ep22

[image]

Comment: Now, that is a nerdy question. I hope I get answers. :)

Comment: Misaki is a chronic liar, so she probably just made this up.

Comment: I agree with that. However, I see many references in this anime, so I ended up wondering if it was real. || If you happen to show some lies (since you say it is chronic) Misaki has told and come to a conclusion saying "Maybe, it is just a lie." as an answer, I will accept it as valid answer in two days. :) You think you have just commented, but you already answered.

Comment: She does mix in some truths with her lies, so this is a reasonable question. I just commented because I'm not sure. She seems to get more and more transparent about her lies in the later episodes of the series, and this study sounds pretty implausible, but there are all sorts of weird studies out there, so that's why I can't say for sure. I might look into this more later.

Comment: While researching about this, there are many thoughts that come to my mind. First and foremost, this research seems *too general* and doesn't say anything about time period or demography, which make it nearly impossible to be found (e.g. "Does this research apply to world-wide? A specific country?", "When was it taken?", "What's the target audience of the research?"). Next, if we're looking on anime's context... Nakahara seems to be pessimistic about her life (her "NHK" means that), and the research is linked to their god's existence. [cnt'd]

Comment: (in short, "The world where people live their life mostly miserably was created by this god"). This might be a point where the research was done not by scientifically, but by certain religious organization (however, this may be a bit of a stretch, so ignore this first). Next, assuming this research is done in Japan, Japanese are infamous with their depression due to their life culture. Searching "90% misery 10% fun" in Japanese gave many result with similar base, from "90% misery" to "80% misery", also "70% misery", and this term seems to be used by psychiater to assist their patients. [cnt'd]

Comment: (e.g. "Life is full of misery. However, that little happiness makes us able to try harder" - [loosely translated from HikiNeet](http://hikineet.com/life-happy-unhappy/))... in the end, I found this question interesting, but to be able to find this specific research seems impossible. It's more of philosophical statement than a research.

Comment: Thanks, it was a very explicit explanation. Maybe, you may want to form these thoughts as an answer?